# Aspx in kentico

Tags: .net, kentico

I'm very new with kentico and I'm a junior .net developer. I have created from scratch my master page in visual studio. My question is : how do I use it in my kentico portal for my page templates? 
Thanks

Comment: Hi Denis, your question is going to be closed because it is too broad. See the [How do I ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) page for tips that will help improve your chances of getting good answers (and keep your question from being closed).  For help getting started with Kentico, see the [Developing websites](https://docs.kentico.com/k11/developing-websites) page on their site.

Comment: Thanks . I have just modified . Is it now fine?

Comment: It may still get closed. This site get a LOT of low quality questions so the standards here are intentionally very high. You need to show us what you have done to try and solve the problem yourself and exactly why that is not working for you.  See [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users).  As for your master page, try [these steps](https://docs.kentico.com/k10/developing-websites/developing-websites-using-aspx-templates/creating-master-pages-for-aspx-templates)

Comment: Hi Dennis, I think an important question is to ask why you have chosen the ASPX development approach.  There is nothing wrong with it, but if you are new to Kentico, you may find working with the Portal approach helps you get up to speed.  I know for my first Kentico site that I went ASPX first because that was what I knew.  I certainly whish I'd foind portal earlier on though.

Comment: As beginner, I try to develop website with different development models. It's just to improve my kentico skills.

Answer (score 2):

Even though your question is pretty broad, you might want to start out by looking at Kentico's documentation and understanding what the development models are and how you handle each one.

https://docs.kentico.com/k10/developing-websites/choosing-the-right-development-model

Comment: Thanks Brenden for the link. My concern was : how do I use my master page in my kentico portal for my page templates?

Comment: My suggestion still stands.  Start with the documentation and dig through each of the development models to learn more about each of them.  This will help you understand it more than someone telling you how to get somewhat started.

Comment: Thank you Brenden for your advices. I will

Answer (score 1):

ASPX master pages themselves don't sit within Kentico, you'll need to add the master page into the ASPX template code in the standard `whatever.aspx` page in the usual way (`MasterPageFile="~/SomeMasterPage.Master"`).  It can be a bit confusing, as in Portal, you also have the concept of [*master pages*](https://docs.kentico.com/k11/developing-websites/developing-websites-using-the-portal-engine/creating-portal-engine-master-pages) but these are a little different.

To use your page portal, check through [Kentico's documentation on creating master pages for ASPX templates](https://docs.kentico.com/k11/developing-websites/developing-websites-using-aspx-templates/creating-master-pages-for-aspx-templates) and make sure you've covered off all the basic steps.  There is also an accompanying page about [creating ASPX page templates](https://docs.kentico.com/k11/developing-websites/developing-websites-using-aspx-templates/creating-aspx-page-templates) which may be of use to you.

Comment: Thank you very much. That was one of my concern

Answer (score 0):

Let me try answering your question.
 1. Create your ASPX page in Visual Studio with or Without .master page. Really doesn't matter.
 2. Page Template > Create new page template in Kentico CMS (select newly created aspx page in visual studio); make sure you select "ASPX page" as Template type. Save and go back to Pages.
 3. Make sure that you don't have root page as normal page and select blank or any "ASPX page" template you may have created in kentico CMS.
 4. You can start creating your web site pages under root:PageType: Root.

Good luck.